# How can i pass Label from viewController to another one without using segue?

Tags: arrays, swift, delegates, closures, nsnotificationcenter

Hi im new in swift and im trying to build a store application, i already build it but i have a problem with only one thing which is , i want to pass the data ( label, image, price label ) to another viewController without using segue. I tried all the method ( delegate, notificationCenter, closure ) but i didn't solve it.

this is a picture for new project i create it to explain what i want to do exactly .

[image]

i hope i get the solution because i search alot for it maybe for months but i didn't solve my problem :(

this is my code

passingViewController

```
             import UIKit

    extension passingDataViewController : textDelegate {
        func sendText(withText: String) {
           Label.text = withText
    
       }


     }


     class receivingDataViewController: UIViewController {


       @IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

    
      
      }



     }
```

receivingDataViewController

```
            import UIKit

       extension passingDataViewController : textDelegate {
         func sendText(withText: String) {
           Label.text = withText
    
      }


     }


     class receivingDataViewController: UIViewController {


       @IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

    
    
            }



         }
```

Comment: You need to send String instead of UILabel ... please include code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: you should probably explain why you don't want to use delegates - which would solve this easily

Comment: @Russell because i try it but it didn't work for me, or maybe i didn't use it well, im new in development at all :) also when i watch videos on YouTube it only pass data from UITextField to UILabel and what i want is pass UILabel to UIlabel . did you get it ??

Comment: @power - you need to solve the real problem, which is that you couldn't get delegates to work, rather than finding an obscure solution.  The first thing to remember is that you are NOT passing a text field or a label between controllers - you are passing DATA, which is then used to populate a text field, label, or whatever you need.  Go back to your delegate examples, and try again - then post a new question including the code showing what you have tried.  Good luck

Comment: @Russell ok i will try it and i will edit on my code, thanks alot and i hope i solve my problem :)

Comment: @Russell i did it this way using delegate but i didn't get what i want so, help please

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain how you're creating the new controllers, but here's a simple example that just uses a tab controller.  This makes use of a shared singleton to pass around the delegate, but if you're creating each controller programatically, you could update the delegate when you create each new instance.

For this example, I have created a singleton that contains the delegate

```
import Foundation

class SharedSingleton : NSObject
{
    var updateDelegate         : UpdateDelegate?

    static let sharedInstance = SharedSingleton()
}
```

And then we define the protocol you're using.

In the passing view, you can define it like this

```
protocol UpdateDelegate
{
    func updateDisplay(text : String)
}
```

and you use it (in the passing view like this

```
var sharedInstance = SharedSingleton.sharedInstance

@IBAction func cmdGo(_ sender: Any) {
    sharedInstance.updateDelegate!.updateDisplay(text: txtInput.text!)
}
```

You define the receiving view to use the update protocol

```
class ReceivingViewController: UIViewController, UpdateDelegate {
```

and set up the delegate

```
var sharedInstance = SharedSingleton.sharedInstance

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // setup the delegate through the shared instance
    sharedInstance.updateDelegate = self
}
```

and then implement the update method

```
func updateDisplay(text: String) {
    lblDisplay.text = text
}
```

That's it.  You may need to update your implementation to change how you share the delegate pointer, but that's the process.

Comment: it didn't work :( please can you give me another example or another method that explain how can i pass only the label ?